# regex for fileupload images only - opencart

Tags: regex, opencart, opencart-3

I am using Opencart V3
At the time of registration we need user to submit a scan copy of some document. For this we added a new customer file upload field (admin > customers > custom field). Problem is that regex dont seems to work, this is our regex to allow upload of image files only but its allowing all file extensions.

```
[a-zA-Z_\s0-9:\b]+(\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.pdf|\.PNG|\.JPG\.JPEG|\.pdf|)$
```

Comment: Try removing the pipe at the end and shorten it to `^[\w:+]+\.(png|jpe?g|pdf|PNG|JPE?G|PDF)$` https://regex101.com/r/3eK36B/1

Comment: it didnt work, opencart is still allowing the upload of unknown files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a place in OpenCart to configure allowed file extensions and mime types.

Go to *System - Settings*, tab *Server*. Here you will find **Allowed File Extensions** and **Allowed File Mime Types**. Edit them on your discretion.